# Is possible to create global event in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently i had some code to change the theme of forms

```
 Public Sub SetTheme()
        Dim isDark = CBool(GetData("theme").Equals("dark"))
        My.Settings.theme = If(isDark = True, "light", "dark")
        My.Settings.primary = If(isDark = True, GetData("lightsmoke"), GetData("dark"))
        My.Settings.secondary = If(isDark = True, GetData("light"), GetData("darksmoke"))
        My.Settings.text_color = If(isDark = True, GetData("dark"), GetData("lightsmoke"))
        My.Settings.Save()
   
'Then Fire an event for change all forms (realtime)
'like : RaiseEvent ChangeTheme -> new event
End Sub
```

Just make it understandable, imagine i had this method in all forms

```
Class Form1
  Private Sub Init() Handles Me.Load, Me.ChangeTheme
    'then this will change its theme form dynamically
    BackColor =  My.Settings.primary
    ForeColor =  My.Settings.text_color
  End Sub
End Class
```

**sorry for mistakes, i'm newbie**

Comment: I'm not sure how the code you posted is related to "global events", can you explain what you are trying to do, and what you need events for? If you just want to detect when the system theme has changed, look in to the [SystemEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=net-5.0) class

Comment: Assuming you're getting an actual COLOR back from your `GetData()` method, use [Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077753/set-backgroundcolor-of-every-form-in-vb-net) as suggested by Caius Jard.

Comment: Use the `Shared` keyword to declare an event that anybody can subscribe.  But beware the danger, every form that subscribes the event must explicitly unsubscribe their event handler when the form is closed.  Failure to do so causes a memory leak.  The cleaner OOP way is to have all of these forms implement an interface, iterate Form.OpenForms to make the interface method calls.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i want it to be applied to all forms when client change the theme at same time, **method** `SetTheme()` just for saving new theme and could be called everywhere. After saved, this will fire a global event to all method  were handle for change itself theme...srry for my bad english

Comment: @HansPassant i'll try it, thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Let's say you have the code on `mymaincode.vb`, and you need to call `SetTheme` on `form.vb`

Instead of using

```
Public Sub SetTheme()
```

Use

```
Public Shared Sub SetTheme()
```

Now go to `form.vb` and call it like

```
 mymaincode.SetTheme()
```

Comment: I think the user is trying to do it the other way around.  They have one or more forms open, and when the `SetTheme()` method is called, all the open forms would change their theme.  That's how I read it.

Comment: @LarsTech that's what i mean